# My deploy from maven to sonarqube failed. see report below

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project maven-web-application: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.mt:maven-web-application:3.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.mt:maven-web-application:3.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to nexus (http://http://35.182.231.128:7000/repository/Pay-Pal-Snapshot/): transfer failed for http://http://35.182.231.128:7000/repository/Pay-Pal-Snapshot/com/mt/maven-web-application/3.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: Please add the rest of the error output...

Comment: (http://http://35.182.231.128:7000/repository/PayPal-Release/): transfer failed for http://http://35.182.231.128:7000/repository/PayPal-Release/com/mt/maven-web-application/2.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Unknown host http: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]

Comment: Network error... wrong ip/port etc.... ask your ops people...